# Программа по определению комплектующих у ПК на C++

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Я учусь на программиста и захотелось мне сделать аналог AIDA64. Задача сложная, но интересная. Программу хочу пока что сделать без графических библиотек(обычное консольное приложение). Программу хочу сделать под ОС Windows XP/7/8/10 и Linux(X/L/K/Ubuntu + Astra Linux). Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу или статьи, которые помогут мне в этом.
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Расковырять готовое приложение? Какую-нибудь `hardinfo`.

Comment: Под Линукс есть lshw и dmidecode